# Android NFC Cannot Write to Mifare DesFire Card

Tags: android, nfc, mifare

I'm trying to write some data to a Mifare DesFire card with a Galaxy S3 with following lines:

```
private byte[] wrapMessage (byte command, byte[] parameters) throws Exception {
    ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

    stream.write((byte) 0x90);
    stream.write(command);
    stream.write((byte) 0x00);
    stream.write((byte) 0x00);
    if (parameters != null) {
        stream.write((byte) parameters.length);
        stream.write(parameters);
    }
    stream.write((byte) 0x00);

    return stream.toByteArray();
}

boolean isoDepWrite(Tag tag) {
      IsoDep idTag = IsoDep.get(tag);
      idTag.setTimeout(5000);

      String info = "";
      DesfireProtocol dfp = new DesfireProtocol(idTag);
      try {
          idTag.connect();
          info += "Connected to IsoDep Tag...\n";

          int[] appList = dfp.getAppList();
          dfp.selectApp(appList[0]);
          info += "Selected app no: " + appList[0] + "..\n";

          int[] fileList = dfp.getFileList();
          info += "Selected file no: " + fileList[0] + "\n";

          byte[] params = {(byte)fileList[0], 
                           (byte)0x0, (byte)0x0, (byte)0x0, 
                           (byte)0x2, (byte)0x0, (byte)0x0,
                           (byte)0x41, (byte)0x41};
          byte[] message = wrapMessage((byte) 0x3d, params);

          byte[] result = idTag.transceive(message);
          info += "Result bytes: " + convertByteArrayToHexString(result) + "\n";

          toast(info);
          return true;
      } catch (IOException e) {
          info += "Could not connect to IsoDep Tag...\n";
      } catch (Exception e) {
          info += "Error messages: " + e.getMessage() + " -- " + e.getLocalizedMessage() + "\n";
      }

      toast(info);
      return false;
  }
```

The info I get after the communication is:

```
Connected to IsoDep tag...
Selected app no: 1109742 // that shows I connected to an Application
Transceieve result bytes: 91 9e  // PARAMETER ERROR
```

I can connect and read that Application's files, but the file has 0's as bytes in it after I try to write. 0x9E is PARAMETER_ERROR, so I'm doing something wrong wrapping/lining the bytes, any samples of bytes or ideas on this?

**EDIT:** I tried the bytes @nemo recommended:

```
{0x3d, fileList[0], 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x2, 0x0, 0x0, 0x41, 0x41}
```

Now I get "67 00" as result bytes, meaning *LENGTH ERROR* and the file keeps staying the same, only 0's.

**LAST EDIT:** I simply created a new byte array by:

```
wrapMessage(0x3d, rest of the bytes in the list @nemo recommended)
```

And it finally worked. I changed the old one with the working above.

Comment: You cannot print the `result` byte array like that. You need to loop through the individual bytes and print those one at a time.

Comment: Please, check your documentation on what the error code 0x9E means.

Comment: Thanks for quick responses. 9E is PARAMETER_ERROR.

Comment: Please, check your documentation for the exact details of the WriteData command.

Comment: That's what I can't find, the exact lining of the bytes. I'll try the bytes in this link: http://pastebin.com/UtQQZ1xN

Comment: Obvious question: are you sure that file is writable and you have the right keys?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you got your `Write` command wrong, but this is a shot in the dark.

According to the official DESFire documentation (try searching for `M075031`) `WriteData` is defined as follows:

```
WriteData(FileNo, Offset, Length, Data)
```

As a byte stream this would look like this:

```
WriteCmd FileNo  Offset (3 byte)  Length (3 byte)  Data (0 to 52 byte)
[0x3D]   [0x00]  [0x00 0x00 0x00] [0x00 0x00 0x00] [0x00 ... 0x00]
```

It's even possible to write 59 byte more than those 52 byte, but that's not important here.

IMO you should make a new array with the needed data for the WriteCmd like this:

```
{0x3d, fileList[0], 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x2, 0x0, 0x0, 0x41, 0x41}
```

Which should write 2 (0x2) bytes (0x41 and 0x41) to the file identified by `fileList[0]`.

**Edit:** Updated offset, order is LSB to MSB.

Comment: Thank you for your effort. I tried your stream of bytes and got 67 00 as result bytes. However, the file is still only 0's.

Comment: Any errors? Same error? Did you read the spec? Mind updating the question?

Comment: `0x67` is, according to the spec, an error code for 'wrong length'. I may have been mistaken with the byte order of length, try fiddling with it and report if it worked, please :)

Comment: Tried 0x2 MSB->LSB, but no luck. Can you write this spec you're looking to, please?

Comment: Tried "0x20 0x0 0x0", "0x0 0x0 0x2", "0x0 0x0 0x02" and no luck again. Tried to write back the read file back (has length 15), with "0xf0 0x0 0x0", "0xf 0x0 0x0", "0x0 0x0 0xf" and "0x0 0x0 0x0f", also.

Comment: I already wrote, which term you need to look for, to find the spec. Try searching for `M075031`. AFAIK this is closed material (marked as confidential for reasons unknown) and, as such, I can't link to it. Did you get different errors while fiddling with the length attribute?

Comment: Did you just send this array without wrapping it? What I meant was, that you send the array using your `wrapMessage` like this:
`wrapMessage((byte)0x3d, {fileList[0], 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x2, 0x0, 0x0, 0x41, 0x41})`.

Comment: Yes, I sent non-wrapped message. Besides, wrapped message always give PARAMETER_ERROR

Comment: Non-wrapped messages will not bring you anywhere. I would like you to test the wrapMessage call I just wrote and report back. Also check, that the file you're editing is of the correct type. It is possible, that you're trying to edit a special file.

Comment: So in this case, you recommend to use my wrapMessage function, send 0x3d as command and rest of the bytes you wrote as byte array?